# Can I send complex data when navigating via component.navigate()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference, navigatetocomponent

I have an order details lightning component page that makes an api call in the `init` action call to get all the order details (a giant 2k line json object).

Once that page loads, there's an "Item Details" button that navigates to a new tab. I know I can pass simple query string parameters in the page reference (`state` property) that gets passed into the `component.navigate()` call (see [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm)). But my question is:

***Is there a way I can send the entire json object from the Order Details page to the Item Details page?***

Comment: why don't you use the browsers localstorage for that?

Comment: @glls - ha, funny I literally came up with that exact solution last night :)

Comment: ill flag it as a duplicate, so users can refer to the Answer in that post.

Comment: @glls - fine with me - thanks.